# get data- attributes values without pass HTML element id

Tags: jquery, html, dom, unobtrusive-javascript, custom-data-attribute

I have  INPUT HTML tag with type as hidden in view.It looks as follows:

```
     <input type="hidden" data-abc-value1="value1" data-abc-value2="value2" data-abc-
         value3="value3"/>
```

I would like to get the values of data- attributes(data-abc-value1,data-abc-value2,data-abc-value3) without passing element id to it.

Can i somehow find matching data-abc(which is common) attributes for the element and get its values.So that i can avoid dependency on element id to get data -* value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, this may help you

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" data-abc-value1="value1" data-abc-value2="value2" data-abc-value3="value3" />
```

**Script**

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(i, e){
    $.each(e.attributes, function(j,v){
        if(/^data-abc/.test(v.nodeName)) {
            console.log(v.nodeName, v.nodeValue);
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo JS** http://jsfiddle.net/UYNsw/

Comment: It does work but is it effective? This traverses all hidden inputs and all their attributes in two nested eaches, so complexity grows exponentially... 
Why not use some sort of unique ids for each input/record it is assciated to?

Comment: Of course, Using unique id will be effective and increase the performance, but @SCP doesn't want to use an id for some reason. My suggestion will be, instead of traversing all the hidden inputs use class at least the number of iteration can be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't provide a way to query by partial attribute names, so you're going to have to get all hidden inputs and then filter the results by attribute using a regular expression:

```
$(function() {
    var inputs = $('input[type="hidden"]').filter(function() {
        var attrs = this.attributes; //get attribute collection for this element
        for(var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
            if(/data-abc-*/.test(attrs[i].name)) {
                return true; //adds this element to the jquery collection
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    //do something with inputs

});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/UPH6R/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/UPH6R/1/)

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery is available use the `.attr()` function to get w3c invalid attributes.
Also use `.eq(0)` to make sure you select the first and only 1 hidden input field. In case of more hidden input fields there's no guarantee this is gonna work.

```
var inp1 = $("input[type=hidden]").eq(0),
    val1 = inp1.attr("data-abc-value1"),
    val2 = inp1.attr("data-abc-value2"),
    val3 = inp1.attr("data-abc-value3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out sample at jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vijaypatel/xk42F/

```
$.fn.filterData = function (set) {
    var elems = $([]);
    this.each(function (i, e) {
        $.each($(e).data(), function (j, f) {
            if (j.substring(0, set.length) == set) {
                elems = elems.add($(e));
            }
        });
    });
    return elems;
}

$.each($('input').filterData('abc'), function (index, value) {
            alert($(this).attr('data-abc-value1'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get them by

```
$("input[type='hidden']").attr('data-abc-value1')
//or 
$('input[data-abc-value1]').attr('data-abc-value1')
```